# How to prevent no existing json properties to be deserialiezed in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON response like this

```
{
    car:100,
    house:200,
    bike:300
}
```

But sometimes some of the properties doesn't come in the response. Like this (house is missing)

```
{
    car:100,
    bike:300
}
```

I'm deserializing with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);`

with this Test model

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "car")]
    public int Car{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "house")]
    public int House{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bike")]
    public int Bike{ get; set; }
}
```

**Now the problem:**
In the second example, where house is missing I'm stil getting the object test to have the propery House set in 0.

There is any way to make this properties optional, I want my model doesn't have the missing property.

**Other thought**
While I was writing this post I thought that maybe this does't make any sense at all, maybe the model is the 'model' why it should be different in different instances..may be is just wrong.

Any answer will be much apreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of `int` is 0. If `House` is optional, make it nullable.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="house")]
public int? House { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your properties to be `nullable` types - for example `int? House { get; set; }`